# Some parts Python's yfinance module not working. print(yf.Ticker("AMD").info['longName'])

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

'''
import yfinance as yf

stock_name = yf.Ticker("AMD").info

print(stock_name['website'])

print(stock_name['longName'])

print(stock_name['longBusinessSummary'])

'''

Can anyone let me know why this isn't working anymore. Just a few weeks ago it was working just fine. Was there any change in yfinance module.

You get KeyError: 'longName'

Comment: I just installed the latest version and it works for me. Maybe your `yfinance` module is corrupted. Try uninstall it and reinstall again.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The version was out. Uninstall and reinstall did the trick.